# JHipster liquibase

Tags: csv, spring-boot, liquibase, jhipster

I'm getting started with JHipster and am attempting to initialize my data using liquibase.  I have added two entities via the JHipster yo task and have added my two csv files into the /resources/config/liquibase directory and added the relevant loadData section to my "added entity" change log files to point at the CSV's.  I had to update the MD5hash in the databasechangelog table and the app is running BUT, the CSV files don't seem to get picked up via the loadData elements I added to the "added entity" XML files. No data is inserted.  Any ideas how to go about running this down?

Answer (score 2):

If you updated the MD5 hashes in the changelog table, I suspect your change log files will not be run because Liquibase will think that they have already been run. I would rather set to null the MD5 hashes and re-start the app.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution for me:
 1. Delete row in databasechangelog
 2. Delete table
 3. Re-start app
Liquibase re-generated table with csv and loaded all data to database.
I hope I helped you :)